# What is the right formatting of DTD when an Element can both contain PCDATA and an other ELEMENT

Tags: xml, dtd

I am provided a XML file and I am suppose to write DTD for the data set.

This is a snippet of the part I am struggling with.

```
<Course Number="CS124" Prerequisites="CS107 CS109" Instructors="DJ" Enrollment="60">
  <Title>From Languages to Information</Title>
  <Description>
    Natural language processing. Cross-listed as
    <Courseref Number="LING180"/>
    . 
    </Description>
</Course>
<Course Number="CS143" Prerequisites="CS107" Instructors="AA" Enrollment="90">
  <Title>Compilers</Title>
  <Description>
    Principles and practices for design and implementation of compilers and interpreters.
  </Description>
</Course>
```

What is the correct way to make the DTD fit the XML, when there is PCDATA in the element, but also optionally a other ELEMENT? (See ELEMENT Description)

I thought something like this would work:

```
<!ELEMENT Description ((#PCDATA | Courseref)*)>
```

But then I get a parse error:

> ContentDecl : Name or '(' expected

What is the correct way to write out the DTD for this this XML to be valid?

Comment: Personally I'd markup the text with a tag say Preamble, and avoid getting into this mess in the first place.

Comment: Oh and out of curiosity why are you still using DTDs?

Comment: It for a course on databases.

Comment: Even more useful to use a schema then.

Comment: That`s the next step in the course. DTD was mandatory to complete.

Comment: Ah, that explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many parentheses:

```
<!ELEMENT Description (#PCDATA | Courseref)*>
```

Comment: Is that going to work anyway? Element has PCDATA and a CourseRef. Not sure myself as I'd go along way to avoid the entire situation.

Comment: Yes, it will work. That declaration says that a `Description` element can have any number (`(...)*`) of `#PCDATA` and `Courseref` child elements in any order. It is not uncommon to see elements inside of text. Think of formatted XML comments in code, for instance. Or in this case, maybe a Course viewer where `Courseref` elements are replaced with links when presented to the user in a UI.

Comment: Cheers, hopefully I'll never need it, but just in case. Always been a big fan of marking up the stuff I want to mark up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!ELEMENT Courseref EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST Courseref Number CDATA #IMPLIED>
```